# Django, как создать уникальное поле задним числом

Tags: python, django

Потребовалось внедрить уникальное поле в существующую модель
например:
foo = models.CharField('Уникальное поле', max_length=40, unique=True)
Как это можно сделать, если в базе уже 100000 строк?

Comment: Ну, как обычно - просто сделать миграцию?

Comment: Меняете модель без признака уникальности, применяете миграцию, вручную или скриптом заполняете поле в записях, меняете модель, поставив признак уникальности, применяете миграцию

Comment: Ну план у меня примерно такой и сложился. Я думал, что есть другие способы. Может быть поле default могло бы быть вызываемым. Например get_random_string какой нибудь

Comment: Ну так-то да, поле default действительно может быть вызываемым. Но как это относится к вопросу?

Comment: А вообще тут есть пример готовой миграции https://allaboutdjango.com/django-how-to-add-migration-for-unique-keys/

Comment: Может ли оно быть использовано, что бы заполнить поля произвольными уникальными значениями в момент применения миграций? У меня не получилось.